# Get HTML output in a window in c++ using Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to C++. I really need to know how to get the output of HTML file in a window instead of getting that in browser. I searched so many sites. I got to know by using Tidy library, will get that but I don't know how to proceed with that.

Can any one please tell me how I will get the HTML output in a window?

I am using WIN32 API.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to do; are you asking how to get an image of some rendered HTML? Do you want to display HTML as text (which is is already)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you would like to display HTML.

Internet Explorer as an ActiveX control should work for you, you can host HTML pages within your application. It is a deep subject, but you can get started by looking up information on the interface:

```
IWebBrowser2
```

If you are creating a windows application, open your dialog editor and add a reference to the MS Web Browser control, I can't tell you specifically what it is, but it should be in the list of COM controls available